# print screen for start view on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, start-menu

Where is the folder of pictures where I took for the screenshot of start view on Windows 8 after I pressed the <kbd>PrintScrn | Sysrq</kbd> button on my keyboard.

Or is this key functional for the Start view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> and the screenshot will be saved as a .png to your Pictures Library under the Screenshot directory.

> Libraries\Pictures\Screenshots\Screenshot (1).png

Another way to capture your screen is to use <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>, which copies the screenshot to your keyboard. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> does the same thing, but only captures the current window, which is really useful!

However, my favorite way to capture screenshots is Steps Recorder.

[image]

Once you start recording, it will record every step you take, whether that be a mouse click or a key press. Once you're done hit Stop Record and it'll give you a collection of photos documenting your steps.

Answer (score 5):

Hitting <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> will save the screenshot to a "Screenshots" folder in your Pictures library.

Note that simply hitting the <kbd>print screen</kbd> key does not actually save the picture anywhere (rather it copies a screenshot to your clipboard), just as with previous versions of Windows.

Comment: To whoever downvoted- Care to comment and explain the downvote so that I can improve it?

Comment: Ah a good answer and I don't know why it get downvote. But whoever the downvoter don't know how to answer :P

Answer (score 1):

The print screen button doesn't take screenshots. Well it does but you need to paste the picture into paint or something then save the picture in order for it to become a screenshot.