# How do I prevent the Windows 8 logon screen defaulting to VPN Connection?

Tags: vpn, windows-8, login-screen

I recently (re-)installed the [Shrewsoft VPN Client](http://www.shrew.net/) on my Windows 8 machine. Since then, at startup or after logging out, the logon screen defaults to the following screen:

```
Shrew Soft VPN Client
[VPN Connection combobox]
[Username field]
[Password field]

Windows Login
[Domain field]
[Username field]
[Password field]
```

*(can't find a way to get a screenshot of the logon screen without installing third-party software)*

I have to click the <- button to go back to the User Selection screen.

The VPN Client screen doesn't even show anything useful. The combo box doesn't have anything to select.

*Is there any way to make the user selection screen show up by default, or at least select a default user to show?*

Comment: Have you tried `PrintScrn` and `Win+PrintScrn`? See http://superuser.com/questions/495115/print-screen-for-start-view-on-windows-8

Comment: Yes. They don't work in the Lock and Logon screens. There are utilities that allow screenshotting these screens, but I don't particularly want to install them specifically for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by uninstalling Shrewsoft VPN Client, then reinstalling it, but unselecting *Credentials Provider*. This removes the VPN Connection from the available users and restores the logon screen to selecting a user.

This doesn't help if you actually need the Credentials Provider and don't want the VPN Connection showing up by default.